# Add WebJobs to WebApp with Azure Fluent API

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, fluent

Is it possible to use the Azure Fluent API to add a WebJob to a WebApp? I'm not finding any documentation describing this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is no, and that you are required to use the `Azure Kudu WebJob API`

*More information about that can be found:*
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/using-the-azure-webjob-api/

Answer (score 0):

As Lachie said, it seems that there is no Fluent API support to add WebJobs, you could use [WebJobs KUDU API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to achieve it.

I do a demo for that. It works correctly in my site. The following is my detail steps:

**Preparation**:

1.The WebJob API require **Basic Authentication** using the publishing credentials, you could go to your webapp in azure portal to click `Get publish profile` and download it to get username and userpassword.

2.Zip the WebJob to be published file.

**Steps**:

1.Create a C# console project.

2.Add the following code in the Program.cs file.

```
string userName = "$name";
string userPassword = "pass";
string webAppName = "webappname";
string webJobName = "webjobname";
var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{userName}:{userPassword}"));
var file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"webjob zip file path");
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/zip");
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + "api/continuouswebjobs/"+webJobName;
    var httpContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    httpContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachement;filename="+ webjob.exe);
    var response2 = client.PutAsync(requestURl, httpContent).Result;
}
```

**Note**: The `filename` should be in the `Content-Dispostion` header. Here I deploy the continuous webjob, if you want to deploy trigger webjob, you could change `continuouswebjobs` to `triggeredwebjobs`.

3.Test from the local.
[image]
4.Check the published result on azure.

[image]